# Building with Armadillo and MKL libraries for x86 (win32)

Tags: python, c++, armadillo, intel-mkl

I got Link error displayed for some portion of codes based on armadillo header file in Visual Studio C++ 2017 following steps described on corresponding guides for x64 (with corresponding x64->x86 changes).

I have downloaded Armadillo latest stable release (armadillo-9.200.6.tar) from their official website. I have also downloaded MKL library for 64-bit WIndows 10 running on Intel i5 processor from Intel website. And I have linked them in Visual Studio 2017 as follows:

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `VC++ Directories` > `Include Directories`: (**Note:** *lines prefixed with asterisk(*) are included as part of armadillo setup*)

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\armadillo-9.200.6\include
* C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\winrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Include\um
```

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `VC++ Directories` > `Library Directories`: (**Note:** *lines prefixed with asterisk(*) are included as part of armadillo setup*)

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\armadillo-9.200.6\examples\lib_win64
* C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\lib\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\lib\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\x86
```

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `C/C++` > `General` > `Additional Include Directories`: (**Note:** *lines prefixed with asterisk(*) are included as part of armadillo setup*)

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl\include
* C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\armadillo-9.200.6\include
C:\Python36_86\include
```

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `General` > `Additional Library Directories`: (**Note:** *lines prefixed with asterisk(*) are included as part of armadillo setup*)

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl\lib\ia32_win
C:\Python36_86\libs
```

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional Dependencies`: (**Note:** *lines prefixed with asterisk(*) are included as part of armadillo setup*)

```
* mkl_core.lib
* mkl_sequential.lib
* mkl_intel_lp64.lib
* lapack_win64_MT.lib
* blas_win64_MT.lib
```

I am developing C++ modules as extensions for Python, hence I am using target platform of Win32. Fortunately some portions of the armadillo code is working okay while for some it's showing the error as list below in the problem statement. This is the code that I am trying to build. It's basically to import numpy arrays, multiply them and return it as Python object. I am doing two trials. Trial 1: multiplying it normally using three for-loops (it is commented here), which is working successfully. Trial 2 is using armadillo (The line where from the error originates is indicated with help of a comment). The code is:

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <Python.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

#define PyTuple_GET_ITEM PyTuple_GetItem
#define PyTuple_GET_SIZE PyTuple_Size
#define PyArray_FLOAT NPY_FLOAT
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

//Taking two numpy array as arguments, multiplying the two numpy arrays and
// returning it back as python object
static PyArrayObject *mmult(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *vec1, *vec2;  

    (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &vec1, &vec2));

    PyArrayObject *cvec1, *cvec2;

    cvec1 = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_FROM_OTF(vec1, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    cvec2 = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_FROM_OTF(vec2, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);

    npy_intp *shape1 = PyArray_DIMS(cvec1);
    npy_intp *shape2 = PyArray_DIMS(cvec2);

    npy_intp shape3[2] = { shape1[0], shape2[1] };
    PyArray_Descr* cvec3_type = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE);

    PyArrayObject* cvec3 = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_Zeros(2, shape3, cvec3_type,0);

    double *v1, *v2, *v3;
    v1 = (double*)PyArray_DATA(cvec1);
    v2 = (double*)PyArray_DATA(cvec2);
    v3 = (double*)PyArray_DATA(cvec3);


    /* TRIAL 1 : SUCCESSFUL
    for (int i = 0; i < shape1[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shape2[1]; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < shape2[0]; k++) {
                v3[shape3[1]*i+j] += v1[shape1[1] * i + k] *v2[shape2[1] * k + j];
            }
        }
    }
    */
    //TIRAL 2: Wih Armadillo
    arma::Mat<double> A1(shape1[0], shape1[1]);  //Successful
    arma::Mat<double> A2(shape2[0], shape2[1]);
    arma::Mat<double> A3(shape1[0], shape2[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < shape1[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shape1[1]; j++) {   
            A1(i, j) = v1[shape1[1] * i + j];   //Successful
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < shape2[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shape2[1]; j++) {  //Successful
            A2(i, j) = v2[shape2[1] * i + j];
        }
    }

    A3 = A1 * A2;  // -----> This is the line that is creating the errors

    for (int i = 0; i < shape1[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shape2[1]; j++) {
            v3[shape3[1] * i + j] = A3(i, j);
        }
    }


    // This piece of the code also do not work with armadillo. I took this from a demo code.
    // Create a 4x4 random matrix and print it on the screen
    arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(4, 4);
    std::cout << "A:\n" << A << "\n";
    // Multiply A with his transpose:
    std::cout << "A * A.t() =\n";
    std::cout << A * A.t() << "\n";

    return cvec3;
}

//Structure: Defines how C++ function is presented to Python
static PyMethodDef mhps_methods[] = {

    { "mmult", (PyCFunction)mmult, METH_VARARGS, nullptr },
    { nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }

};

//Structure: Defines module as you want it to be referred to in your Python code.
static PyModuleDef mhps_module = {

    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "mhps",
    "faster codes for research modules",
    0,
    mhps_methods

};

//Method: Python calls this method when it loads the module using "import mhps"
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mhps() {
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&mhps_module);
}
```

This is the error that is being generated:

```
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sposv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sdot_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemm_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgesv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgesv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sgemm_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dposv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgemv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zposv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cposv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgemm_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dsyrk_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ssyrk_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ddot_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zgemm_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _dgesv_
module1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cgesv_
```

Comment: Side note: please don't use any "Visual-studio..." tags for questions that don't relate to customizing/using/plugin development (check info on the tag, same for "windows")

Comment: Please check if my edit of title actually reflect what you trying to do (rather than generic error)

Answer (score 0):

It was a small mistake on my part while entering the inputs at:

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional Dependencies`:

```
mkl_intel_c.lib
mkl_sequential.lib
mkl_core.lib
```

I completely replaced it with the above filenames. It's actually the files in the libraries for 32-bit folder in `mkl` folder. Going by the instructions of the article, titled "[Getting started with Armadillo a C++ Linear Algebra Library on Windows, Mac and Linux](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/03/24/getting-started-armadillo-cpp-linear-algebra-windows-mac-linux/)", the author assumed most would be using it for 64-bit and hence did not specify the specific files to be included in the linker input list.