# How to setup complex project with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have project that I was developing for years in Linux.
It depends on MKL, libxml++, GSL and armadillo library.

Its installation structure is done in CMake and project is formed by building a shared library and couple of executables that link to it. There are about 20 classes in the library.

Project structure is:

```
--src
  --executable1.cpp
  --executable2.cpp
  --mysharedlib
    --class1.h
    --class1.cpp
    --...
```

My question is how to install and run this code in Visual Studio in Windows.
I never used VS before and am still going through tutorials. I managed to run my code by installing Ubuntu on WSL, but I I'd like a VS solution as it'd be handy to pass to user not familiar with Linux.

I tried opening the project directory with VS, hoping CMAKE would do all the magic, but expectedly it cannot locate the dependent libraries, so I am now going through web looking how to integrate each to VS. I managed to find armadillo and mkl guide, but I am lost on how to link these libraries to my project codes and whether I should abandon its current cmake setup and start building the code structure differently in VS.

Any links to useful VS tutorials and advices how to this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990567/building-with-armadillo-and-mkl-libraries-for-x86-win32

Comment: Your least problem is the cmake support. Your big problem is the API compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS does have support for CMake, although I have no idea how well VS integrates CMake. If you're not set on using VS, you might want to look into an IDE that uses CMake at it's core, Clion comes to mind. That being said, when coming from Linux you don't have the (initial) luxury of simply installing all the dependencies via a preinstalled package manager.

In order for CMake to find your dependencies (assuming you've configured them by using `find_package()`) you should add the sources of your dependencies to your project in a `thirdparty` folder (name is up to you) and add these dependencies using `add_subdirectory()` instead. This will compile all your dependencies from source, so you might have to configure these dependencies yourself (look into the documentation of your dependencies on how to build them from source).

Another way is to use a package manager that is available on Windows to download, compile and provide your dependencies to your build tools. [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html) comes to mind, claiming to integrate well with CMake by providing a toolchain file that you can pass to CMake when building your project. You might even be able to configure VS to automatically pass this toolchain to CMake whenever it's invoked.

From personal experience, there is no need to convert an existing project to the VS project structure. There's plenty of available solutions and tools available on Windows to work with CMake projects. Going with the cross-platform approach should be preferred unless you're only targeting Windows, using VS to it's fullest then might give you some additional quality of life.

If you have more specific questions regarding this, I suggest that you update your original post or to create separate, specific questions regarding the processes involved in setting up an existing CMake project on Windows.